# the language code for localization in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

According to apple's guide, the language code can be found in [IOS639](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php).However, I tried some codes and failed.

In the code list only chinese exists, but the chinese in China mainland is different in HongHong and so on. I'm confused about it!

Could anyone show me the correct language code list?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [CFLocales](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/Articles/CFLocaleConcepts.html) documentation (under "Locale Naming Conventions") indicates that they'll accept `ISO 639-1` or `ISO 639-2`. Their `ISO 3166-1` link is broken, but Wikipedia lists the [region codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). Apple actually addresses the distinction for Hong Kong specifically in its [language ID section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html):

> However, traditional Chinese is also commonly spoken in Hong Kong and Macao, which means the zh_TW designator is not entirely accurate in those locations. The new standard defines new tags for the traditional Chinese (Hant) and simplified Chinese (Hans) scripts. Thus, traditional Chinese spoken in any country uses the code zh-Hant.

Comment: thanks! it seems that I didn't read the internationalization guide!